# Is there a generic OAuth 2 refresh token URL for Google Console API projects' Google Sign-In?

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, zapier

I'm creating a custom, private app in Zapier's legacy browser-based developer's platform. Google api requires OAuth 2, which I am able to configure correctly with the credentials Google provides after creating a user client (through the first button at this link):

https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in#before_you_begin

It generates the needed credentials as such:

```
{
    "web": {
        "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token", 
        "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs", 
        "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth", 
        "client_id": "1234567890example.apps.googleusercontent.com", 
        "client_secret": "1234567890abcexample", 
        "project_id": "abc123example", 
        "javascript_origins": [
            "https://zapier.com"
        ]
    }
}
```

My issue is Zapier needs to refresh the access token on a regular basis. It has the option to set it up this way with this extra field:

"Refresh Token URL (optional) 
Where we POST to refresh an access_token."

As you can see, Google provided all that I need (client_id, client_secret, token_url, auth_url, etc.) but not a refresh_token_url.

Is there a google refresh token url I can plug into this field in Zapier that will take care of this?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you can reuse the `token_uri`, based on other projects I've seen that do the same thing. Have you tried that?

Comment: Just added the token_url in the refresh token URL field and deployed. I clicked on add an account, the Google sign-in screen came up with  my emails, and when I selected an email account the error window came up:

"Zapier could not connect to your account.

Token named refresh_token was not found in oauth response!"

I even tried it with: https://oauth2.googleapis.com/refresh_token

I'm just groping in the dark at this point haha